# Using non-input elements with Backbone.Syphon

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, contenteditable, marionette

I'm using [Backbone.Syphon](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.syphon/blob/master/apidoc.md) on a project and just loving it, but I've run into a bit of a snag. I need to use some non-standard input elements for input. Specifically some `<div>` and/or `<span>` elements with `contenteditable="true"`.

I've read through the relatively simple documentation but just can't grasp exactly what's necessary for alerting Backbone.Syphon to this customization.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this can't be done the way Syphon is set up, at the moment. It uses the [HTMLFormElement.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.elements) attribute to retrieve the form elements. Since a `<div>` or `<span>` is not a form element, it does not get picked up.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite backbone.syphon.js to make this possible.
Inside the *getForm* function change the line

```
return viewOrForm.$(':input');
```

to say

```
return viewOrForm.$(':input, div.editable');
```